# Ajax POST Request to Flask Application

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to create  a POST request from ajax using input type button. But the request is not sending

Need to send two separate request from each like below

**html**

```
            <input type="button" class="far fa-check-circle" name="hvalid" id="hvalid">
            <input type="button" class="fas fa-times-circle" name="hinvalid" id="hinvalid">
```

**ajax**

```
$(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        var hvalid = $('#hvalid').val();
        var hinvalid = $('#hinvalid').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/pending_val',
            data : {'hvalid':hvalid,
                     'hinvalid':hinvalid},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Flask Route**

```
@data_sources_api.route('/pending_val', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def pending_val():
        if request.method=='POST':
            print(request.form)
```

How `hvalid` and `hinvalid` request can be send separately

Comment: You may be able to use the name attribute to differentiate the buttons. However, the button has no value. What should be sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
 <input type="button" class="far fa-check-circle" name="hButton" id="hvalid">
  <input type="button" class="fas fa-times-circle" name="hButton" id="hinvalid">
```

ajax

```
$(function(){
$('input[name="hButton"]').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pending_val',
        data : {'hvalidity': this.id },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Flask

```
data_sources_api.route('/pending_val',methods=["GET", "POST"])
def pending_val():
    if request.method=='POST':
        print(request.form.get('hvalidity'))
    return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Ending braces of ajax code is outside of formated code. It will be great if you can edit that portion so that newbies will not get confused. Please upvote the question too